# Check <a> elements for attr target=“blank” and if so open new window via JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to open link with `target="_blank"` attribute via JavaScript.

This action required to open popup window in web app, otherwise it’s open in external browser.

I’m using jQuery to detect `target` of the `<a>` element, but the code below doesn’t work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).attr('target')) == "_blank" {
      var win = window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
      win.focus();
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: For what reason are you doing this? It seems unnecessary, as if the element has `target="_blank"` set then it will already open in a new tab, so opening another tab manually is redundant.

Comment: Also note that your braces and parentheses are mismatched and will be causing a syntax error.

Comment: Proposed code doesn’t work. Where the bug.

Comment: If webapp on iOS opens window via JS it opens in popup window instead opening in Safari.

Comment: @EuQu Are you trying to achieve if clicked <a> has target _blank and href is not empty then open link in a new window?

Comment: Instead of `$("a")` and then an `if` statement, just use `$("a[target='_blank']").on(....`. Then you can get rid of the `if` statement completely.

Comment: Also, the second argument to `window.open` is no necessary for your purpose. All you need is `window.open(url)`.

Comment: And, `return false` is also not necessary.

Comment: Try this.

$("a[target='_blank']").on('click', function (event) {
                            if ($(this).attr('href').trim() == ""  )  return false;
                         
                        });

Comment: Scott Marcus, thanks, it works!

Comment: @ScottMarcus without the return false, won't the default action of the `a` kick in, ie open the url in a new tab - so OP gets a window.open and a new tab for each click?

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` instead of return false.

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('target')) == "_blank" {` <-- yikes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Scott Marcus — found the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[target='_blank']").on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank').focus();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browsers implementation this will work

There is nothing you can do to make it open in a window rather than a tab.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if ($(this).attr('target') == "_blank") {
              window.open(url, '_blank');
            }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="google.com" target="_blank">eminem</a>
```

Comment: Read my comments to the OP. This is overkill.

Comment: Scott Marcus, post your advice as answer please

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Get all the anchors in the entire document
    // (You can also use document.links to get the links)
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    // Loop through the anchors and add the click handler if it includes the CSS class 'external'
    for ( var i in anchors ) 
        if ( anchors[i].className && anchors[i].className.indexOf('external') != -1 )
            anchors[i].onclick = function () { return !window.open(this); };
</script>
```

or very simple

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var getAnchors=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var i=0;
     for(i=0;i<getAnchors.length;i++){
             getAnchors[i].setAttribute("target","_blank");
    }
    </script>
```